# Run command automatically after terraform apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

How to run a specific terminal command after successful `terraform apply`?

More specifically, I would like to save output variables to some S3 bucket (the state is already in S3, but it contains sensitive output, so the bucket has a restricted access), and while this feature request [is still open](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/13470), I'm using this workaround:

```
terraform apply && terraform output -json | aws s3 cp - s3://bucket/output.json
```

But would it be possible to force terraform to call this command automatically?

Comment: How do you run Terraform? Via CI? Locally? Do you use wrapper scripts or directly call the Terraform commands?

Comment: I use a plain CLI. Essentially I have a `Makefile` with the command `terraform apply && terraform output ...` for deployment target. It is ok, but not elegant. Also it adds build time, as terraform output takes considerable time when the state is in the S3 bucket.

Answer (score -2):

Though it may seem like more upfront work and isn't exactly uploading to s3 using terraform, I would use a tool such as Jenkins which has both terraform and AWS plugins. Then you can continually add to your pipelines and see past runs.

See:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Terraform+Plugin
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/S3+Plugin

You could configure Jenkins to run the terraform and then you should be able to use the s3 plugin to upload to AWS.